# Why is my Docker volume not working in a remote build box?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, circleci, docker-volume

I am attempting to add a volume to a Docker container that will be built and run in a Docker Compose system on a hosted build service (CircleCI). It works fine locally, but not remotely. CircleCI provide an SSH facility I can use to debug why a container is not behaving as expected.

The relevant portion of the Docker Compose file is thus:

```
  missive-mongo:
    image: missive-mongo
    command: mongod -v --logpath /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log --logappend
    volumes:
    - ${MONGO_LOCAL}:/data/db
    - ${LOGS_LOCAL_PATH}/mongo:/var/log/mongodb
    networks:
    - storage_network
```

Locally, if I do `docker inspect integration_missive-mongo_1` (i.e. the running container name, I will get the volumes as expected:

```
    ...
    "HostConfig": {
        "Binds": [
            "/tmp/missive-volumes/logs/mongo:/var/log/mongodb:rw",
            "/tmp/missive-volumes/mongo:/data/db:rw"
        ],
    ...
```

On the same container, I can shell in and see that the volume works fine:

```
docker exec -it integration_missive-mongo_1 sh
/ # tail /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log 
2017-11-28T22:50:14.452+0000 D STORAGE  [initandlisten] admin.system.version: clearing plan cache - collection info cache reset
2017-11-28T22:50:14.452+0000 I INDEX    [initandlisten] build index on: admin.system.version properties: { v: 2, key: { version: 1 }, name: "incompatible_with_version_32", ns: "admin.system.version" }
2017-11-28T22:50:14.452+0000 I INDEX    [initandlisten]      building index using bulk method; build may temporarily use up to 500 megabytes of RAM
2017-11-28T22:50:14.452+0000 D INDEX    [initandlisten]      bulk commit starting for index: incompatible_with_version_32
2017-11-28T22:50:14.452+0000 D INDEX    [initandlisten]      done building bottom layer, going to commit
2017-11-28T22:50:14.454+0000 I INDEX    [initandlisten] build index done.  scanned 0 total records. 0 secs
2017-11-28T22:50:14.455+0000 I COMMAND  [initandlisten] setting featureCompatibilityVersion to 3.4
2017-11-28T22:50:14.455+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] waiting for connections on port 27017
2017-11-28T22:50:14.455+0000 D COMMAND  [PeriodicTaskRunner] BackgroundJob starting: PeriodicTaskRunner
2017-11-28T22:50:14.455+0000 D COMMAND  [ClientCursorMonitor] BackgroundJob starting: ClientCursorMonitor
```

OK, now for the remote. I kick off a build, it fails because Mongo won't start, so I use the SSH facility that keeps a box alive after a failed build.

I first hack the DC file so that it does not try to launch Mongo, as it will fail. I just get it to sleep instead:

```
  missive-mongo:
    image: missive-mongo
    command: sleep 1000
    volumes:
    - ${MONGO_LOCAL}:/data/db
    - ${LOGS_LOCAL_PATH}/mongo:/var/log/mongodb
    networks:
    - storage_network
```

I then run the `docker-compose up` script to bring all containers up, and then examine the problematic box: `docker inspect integration_missive-mongo_1`:

```
    "HostConfig": {
        "Binds": [
            "/tmp/missive-volumes/logs/mongo:/var/log/mongodb:rw",
            "/tmp/missive-volumes/mongo:/data/db:rw"
        ],
```

That looks fine. So on the host I create a dummy log file, and list it to prove it is there:

```
bash-4.3# ls /tmp/missive-volumes/logs/mongo
mongodb.log
```

So I try shelling in, `docker exec -it integration_missive-mongo_1 sh` again. This time I find that the folder exists, but not the volume contents:

```
/ # ls /var/log
mongodb
/ # ls /var/log/mongodb/
/ #
```

This is very odd, because the reliability of volumes in the remote Docker/Compose config has been exemplary up until now.

### Theories

My main one at present is that the differing versions of Docker and Docker Compose could have something to do with it. So I will list out what I have:

- Local

  - Host: Linux Mint
  - Docker version 1.13.1, build 092cba3
  - docker-compose version 1.8.0, build unknown
- Remote

  - Host: I suspect it is Alpine (it uses `apk` for installing)
  - I am using the `docker:17.05.0-ce-git` image supplied by CircleCI, the version shows as `Docker version 17.05.0-ce, build 89658be`
  - Docker Composer is installed via Pip, and getting the version produces `docker-compose version 1.13.0, build 1719ceb`.

So, there is some version discrepancy. As a shot in the dark, I could try bumping up Docker/Compose, though I am wary of breaking other things.

What would be ideal though, is some sort of advanced Docker commands I can use to debug why the volume appears to be registered but is not exposed inside the container. Any ideas?

Comment: It sounds like [circleci might control containers remotely](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/docker-compose-yml-and-volume-mounts/10043/7). What do you need the bind mounts for? Can you use named volumes instead?

Comment: Ah, good find @Matt, and thanks - just after posting, [I found this](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/docker-compose-yml-and-volume-mounts/10043/12) and [this](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/docker-in-docker-not-mounting-volumes/14037/2). Your link is useful, as it explains _why_ this does not work. My use case is running integration tests on CircleCI - I bring 11 containers up and then run some browser tests.

Comment: I don't _strictly_ need the mount, since I could turn it off for these tests. However, I do use it in live (storing Mongo logs on the host, and sharing them with a logger container) and so my ideal would be to ensure any failure with the volume causes the integration tests to fail. However, it is not critical, and I am minded to just turn it off in CircleCI (I've been at this trivial task for some hours already `;-)`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CircleCI runs `docker-compose` remotely from the Docker daemon](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/docker-compose-yml-and-volume-mounts/10043/7) so local bind mounts don't work.

A [named volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/#create-and-manage-volumes) will default to the `local` driver and would work in CircleCI's Compose setup, the volume will exist where ever the container runs.

Logging should generally be left to stdout and stderr in a single process per container setup. Then you can make use of a [logging driver plugin](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/overview/) to ship to a central collector. MongoDB defaults to logging to stdout/stderr when run in the foreground.

Combining the volumes and logging:

```
version: "2.1"

services:

  syslog:
    image: deployable/rsyslog
    ports:
      - '1514:1514/udp'
      - '1514:1514/tcp'

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    command: mongod -v
    volumes:
      - 'mongo_data:/data/db'
    depends_on:
      - syslog
    logging:
      options:
        tag: '{{.FullID}} {{.Name}}'
        syslog-address: "tcp://10.8.8.8:1514"
      driver: syslog

volumes:
  mongo_data:
```

This is a little bit of a hack as the logging endpoint would normally be external, rather than a container in the same group. This is why the logging uses the external address and port mapping to access the syslog server. This connection is between the docker daemon and the log server, rather than container to container.

Comment: Marvellous Matt, thanks - I was beginning to tear my hair out a bit... though thankfully it always seems to grow back. I appreciate your thoughts on how to arrange logging in Docker Compose. That is probably better than my arrangement - all logs are written to an on-host volume per container, and then all volumes are shared with a rsyslog container that forwards the logs to Papertrail. I will try to come back to your post in the long term and see if I can do things in more Dockerish way!

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to add an additional answer to accompany the accepted one. My use-case on CircleCI is to run browser-based integration tests, in order to check that a whole stack is working correctly. A number of the 11 containers in use have volumes defined for various things, such as log output and raw database file storage.

What I had not realised until now was that the volumes in CircleCI's Docker executor do not work, as a result of a technical Docker limitation. As a result of this failure, in each case previously, the files were just written to an empty folder.

In my new case however, this issue was causing Mongo to fail. The reason for that was that I'm using `--logappend` to prevent Mongo from doing its own log rotation on start-up, and this switch requires the path specified in `--logpath` to exist. Since it existed on the host, but the volume creation failed, the container could not see the log file.

To fix this, I have modified my Mongo service entry to call a script in the `command` section:

```
  missive-mongo:
    image: missive-mongo
    command: sh /root/mongo-logging.sh
```

And the script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# The command sets up logging in Mongo. The touch is for the benefit of any
# environment in which the logs do not already exist (e.g. Integration, since
# CircleCI does not support volumes)

touch /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log \
    && mongod -v --logpath /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log --logappend
```

In the two possible use cases, this will act as follows:

- In the case of the mount working (dev, live) it will simply touch a file if it exists, and create it if it does not (e.g. a completely new environment),
- In the case of the mount not working (CircleCI) it will create the file.

Either way, this is a nice safety feature to prevent Mongo blowing up.